# How to make an object in java to be called from outside Bluej

Tags: java, bluej

I'm just entering studing Programming in college, and they give me like homework create one app in java than actualy identify the different types of triangles acording to the sides they'll receive.

I'm just fine with that, but now i'm trying to understand and write the part who call the others methods and show the results outside Bluej.

Can somebody gave me that last method and explain me a little bit how it works?

I really need to see some actual working code to learn how and when make objects from classes, and how to connect the methods to this ones.

**The console is returning me this error:**
non-static variable base cannot be referenced from a static context

**UPDATE:**
Now is returning me:
'.class' espected

in this part of the code:

```
...
 public static void main (int args[]){
        Triangle obj1 = new *Triangle(int[]* args);
        System.out.print(obj1.triangleCheck());
   }
}
```

**NOTE:** the parte between "*" is where it shows the error exist, the "*" are not part of the actual code itself.
**NOTE2:** See it after "UPDATE" to see it on it actual context.

Also, if some of you out there tell me how to improve my code woulde be good too, i'm new in object-oriented languajes.

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {
    int base;
    int ladoa;
    int ladob;
    String res = "";
    public Triangle(int arg[]) {
        Scanner Triangle = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño de la Base del triángulo");
        int base = Triangle.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del lado A del triángulo");
        int ladoa = Triangle.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del lado B del triángulo");
        int ladob = Triangle.nextInt();
    }  
   public String triangleCheck(int base, int ladoa, int ladob) {
       String baseb = Integer.toString(base);
       String sidea = Integer.toString(ladoa);
       String sideb = Integer.toString(ladob);
       String var1 = "";
       String var2 = "";
       String var3 = "";
       String var4 = "";

       int lados=ladoa+ladob;
       String ladoss = sidea + sideb;
       if (base>=(ladoa+ladob)) {
           if (lados==base) {
              var1 = "Es un triángulo equilatero, pues sus lados y su base son todos iguales";
              var2 = "Lado A + Lado B = " + ladoss;
              var3 = "Base = " + baseb;
              res = var1 + "\n" + var2 + "\n" +  var3;
           } else if (ladoa==ladob && lados < base || lados > base){
              var1 = "Es un triánglo isósceles, pues dos de sus lados son iguales y su base es diferente";
              var2 = "Lado A = " + ladoss;
              var3 = "Lado B = " + ladoss;
              var4 = "Base = " + baseb;
              res = var1 + "\n" + var2 + "\n" +  var3 + "\n" +  var4;
           } else if (ladoa > ladob || ladoa < ladob) {
              var1 = "Es un triángulo escaleno, pues sus lados y la base son distintas";
              var2 = "Lado A = " + ladoss;
              var3 = "Lado B = " + ladoss;
              var4 = "Base = " + baseb;
              res = var1 + "\n" + var2 + "\n" +  var3 + "\n" +  var4;
           } else {
              var1 = "Eso no es un triángulo, pues los lados de un triángulo, no pueden ser sumados menores a la base";
              res = var1;
           }
        } else  {
           res = "Eso no es un triángulo, pues los lados de un triángulo, no pueden ser sumados menores a la base";
        }
        return res;
   }
   public static void main (int args[]){
        Triangle obj1 = new Triangle(base, ladoa, ladob);
        System.out.print(obj1.triangleCheck());
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {
    static int base;
    static int ladoa;
    static int ladob;
    String res = "";
    public Triangle(int arg[]) {
        Scanner Triangle = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño de la Base del triángulo");
        int base = Triangle.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del lado A del triángulo");
        int ladoa = Triangle.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del lado B del triángulo");
        int ladob = Triangle.nextInt();
    }  
   public String triangleCheck(int base, int ladoa, int ladob) {
       String baseb = Integer.toString(base);
       String sidea = Integer.toString(ladoa);
       String sideb = Integer.toString(ladob);
       String var1 = "";
       String var2 = "";
       String var3 = "";
       String var4 = "";

       int lados=ladoa+ladob;
       String ladoss = sidea + sideb;
       if (base>=(ladoa+ladob)) {
           if (lados==base) {
              var1 = "Es un triángulo equilatero, pues sus lados y su base son todos iguales";
              var2 = "Lado A + Lado B = " + ladoss;
              var3 = "Base = " + baseb;
              res = var1 + "\n" + var2 + "\n" +  var3;
           } else if (ladoa==ladob && lados < base || lados > base){
              var1 = "Es un triánglo isósceles, pues dos de sus lados son iguales y su base es diferente";
              var2 = "Lado A = " + ladoss;
              var3 = "Lado B = " + ladoss;
              var4 = "Base = " + baseb;
              res = var1 + "\n" + var2 + "\n" +  var3 + "\n" +  var4;
           } else if (ladoa > ladob || ladoa < ladob) {
              var1 = "Es un triángulo escaleno, pues sus lados y la base son distintas";
              var2 = "Lado A = " + ladoss;
              var3 = "Lado B = " + ladoss;
              var4 = "Base = " + baseb;
              res = var1 + "\n" + var2 + "\n" +  var3 + "\n" +  var4;
           } else {
              var1 = "Eso no es un triángulo, pues los lados de un triángulo, no pueden ser sumados menores a la base";
              var2 = "";
              var3 = "";
              var4 = "";
              res = var1;
           }
        } else  {
           res = "Eso no es un triángulo, pues los lados de un triángulo, no pueden ser sumados menores a la base";
        }
        return res;
   }
   public static void main (int args[]){
        Triangle obj1 = new Triangle(int[] args);
        System.out.print(obj1.triangleCheck());
   }
}
```

Any suggestion, idea, comment or something than improve the question would be much apreaciated too

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try naming your scanner something other than Triangle, because you already made a class named Triangle

Comment: Also,   String var1 = "";
       String var2 = "";
       String var3 = "";
       String var4 = ""; is unnecessary.  You can get ride of the =""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason it's giving that error is because your global variables, if they're being accessed from a field that has a `static` modifier, they need to be `static` too. So to get rid of the error, `base`, `ladoa`, and `ladob` need to be `static int`s:

```
// This will remove the problems with the
// error.
static int base;
static int ladoa;
static int ladob;
```

EDIT:
The problem you're now facing with the `.class` expected is because of a mis-interpretation of what I was telling you.

You were calling:

```
new Triangle(arg, arg, arg);
```

when it asks for:

```
new Triangle(int[] args);
```

you just need the argument name (must be an `int[]` to be passed):

```
new Triangle(args);
```

Comment: Thanks you, and the '.class' expected problem, what could be the solution?

Comment: Thanks, i already change the code and i'm using it another one right now, but thanks for the help anyway :S